# Do something if for loop doesn't find what I want

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a common problem and I wanted to know if anyone has a better way of solving it then what I have been doing so far.

I want to loop over an array to find an object and update it. If the object doesn't exist, I want to append it to the array. I am usually working with more complex objects which makes the issue more complex.

```
var movies = [
    { _id: 1, title:"Movie 1" }, 
    { _id: 2, title: "Another Movie" }
];

var myTheater = { location:"here", current_movies: movies };

// A movie to check. The _id may or may not be in movies.
var aMovie = { _id: 3, title: "Something New" };

// boolean flag to let us know if something happened
var updated = false;

// look through all movies and my theater and update as needed
for(var i = 0, len = myTheater.current_movies.length; i<len; i++){
    if( myTheater.current_movies[i]._id === aMovie._id ){
        console.log("Updating movie name.");
        myTheater.current_movies[i].title = aMovie.title;
        updated = true;
        break;
    }
}

// check if anything was updated and add the movie if not
if(!updated){
    myTheater.current_movies.push(aMovie);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this or is using a flag the best option? Thanks!

Comment: You should use `break` to end the loop after you find the object, unless there can be multiple matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the native [**Array.prototype.find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this:

```js
var movies = [{ _id: 1, title:"Movie 1" }, { _id: 2, title: "Another Movie" }];
var myTheater = { location:"here", current_movies: movies };
var aMovie = { _id: 3, title: "Something New" };



// check if there is a movie with the same id as aMovie
var found = myTheater.current_movies.find(m => m._id == aMovie._id);

if(found) // if we found something
  found.title = aMovie.title; // update it's title
else
  /*things to do if nothing was found*/
  console.log("nothing found!");
```

**Arrow Functions:**

The function (callback) I passed to `find` is called [**Arrow Function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You can call `find` using a regular function like this:

```
var found = myTheater.current_movies.find(function(m) {
    return m._id == aMovie._id;
});
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `=>`. Is your find function effectively `currentMovies.find(function(m){ return m._id == aMovie._id }`?

Comment: @jrose See the **Arrow Functions** section in my answer. I added a link to a reference on Mozilla as well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with using `.find()`, but you shouldn't mutate any data inside the testing function. Instead, use it to find the item and act on what it returns (either a movie or `undefined`).

```
function createOrUpdate(draftMovie) {
  var film = movies.find(function(savedMovie){
    return savedMovie._id == draftMovie._id;
  })

  if(film){
    return film.title = draftMovie.title;
  } else {
    return myTheater.currentMovies.push(draftMovie);
  }
}
```

More about `.find()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1):

First you find if **movies** contains the id
If it contains you update  otherwise you just push **aMovie**

Previously you dynamicaly create an array of id to easyly know if **movies** contains an id and where it is located :

```js
var movies = [
        { id: 1, title:"Movie 1" },
        { id: 2, title: "Another Movie" }
    ];
var aMovie = { id: 3, title: "Something New" };
var index = movies.map(x => x.id).indexOf(aMovie.id);
if (index !== -1) movies[index].title = aMovie.title;
else movies.push(aMovie);
console.log(movies);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.find` to check and update if the movie exists and update it if it doesn't

```
var movies = [{ _id: 1, title:"Movie 1" }, 
        { _id: 2, title: "Another Movie" }
    ];
    var myTheater = { location:"here", current_movies: movies };
    var aMovie = { _id: 1, title: "Something New" };
    var movie = myTheater.current_movies.find(function(x){
     if(x._id===aMovie._id){
      console.log("Updating movie name.");
      x.title = aMovie.title;
      return true;  
     }
    });
    if(!movie){
     myTheater.current_movies.push(aMovie);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use id or another attribute as identification, so if the last entry was 100 then you dont have to look for 101. You can just check the size of the array or loop through it and compare the value of id and if it isnt there then you can insert it. Though javascript probably already has some function for doing this.

Comment: Please ANSWER the question instead of giving suggestions. Then if the answer is good, you will get the rep you need to comment instead

Comment: Maybe instead of commenting had you focused on what I wrote, you would understand that it does answer the question. Instead of the title based comparison performed by the OP, id based would yield proper result. Unless you expected me to copy his entire code and change a single self explanatory line, I don't think it was wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that a) I did not vote down and b) yes, copy the code into a [mcve] using the `<>` button like the accepted answer. Please visit the [help] to see how to answer. I could also have kept my comment to myself and left you wondering why your comment was voted down.